# Sending and receiving files in C win32 using a socket

Tags: c, file, socket, winapi, network-file-transfer

I have a piece of code to send and receive files on Windows with C. Is this the right way to do it? And am I guaranteed that the full file will be sent and received?

Receiving function:

```
int recvFile(char path[100], SOCKET y)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    size_t size = BUFSIZE;
    int counter = 0;
    int totalRead = 0;

    // receiving file size
    char b[sizeof(size_t)];
    size_t intTotalReceived = 0;
    size_t intReceived = 0;
    int intSize = sizeof(size_t);

    while (intTotalReceived < intSize)
    {
        intReceived = recv(y, b + intTotalReceived, intSize - intTotalReceived, 0);
        if (intReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("error recv buffer size\n");
        }
        intTotalReceived += intReceived;
    }
    size_t test = ntohl_ch(&b[0]);
    if ((int)test == 666666)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* copyFile;
    fopen_s(&copyFile, path, "wb");
    if (copyFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (totalRead < (int)test)
    {
        int res = recv(y, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
        if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("3 error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 0;
        }
        size = fwrite(buf, 1, res, copyFile);
        counter++;
        totalRead += res;
    }
    fclose(copyFile);
    return 1;
}
```

Sending function:

```
int sendFile(char path[100])
{
    FILE* originalFile;
    errno_t fr = fopen_s(&originalFile, path, "rb");
    if (fr != 0)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        int n = 666666;
        size_t numb = htonl(n);
        char* converted_num = (char*)&numb;
        size_t intSize = sizeof(size_t);
        size_t intSent = 0;
        size_t intTotalSent = 0;
        while (intTotalSent < intSize)
        {
            intSent = send(ClientSocket, converted_num + intTotalSent, intSize - intTotalSent, 0);
            if (intSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("error send %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                break;
            }
            intTotalSent += intSent;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    size_t size = BUFSIZE;
    int counter = 0;

    // getting file size
    int sizeFile = getSizeFile(originalFile);

    // sending file size
    size_t num = htonl(sizeFile);
    char* converted_num = (char*)&num;
    size_t intSize = sizeof(size_t);
    size_t intSent = 0;
    size_t intTotalSent = 0;
    while (intTotalSent < intSize)
    {
        intSent = send(ClientSocket, converted_num + intTotalSent, intSize - intTotalSent, 0);
        if (intSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("error send %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 0;
        }
        intTotalSent += intSent;
    }

    while (size == BUFSIZE)
    {
        size = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, originalFile);
        int r = send(ClientSocket, buf, size, 0);
        if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("1 error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    fclose(originalFile);
    return 1;
}
```

And then in main (receiving part):

```
int r = recvFile(path, y);
if (r == 0)
{
    printf("file error\n");
}
```

Main (sending part):

```
int ret = sendFile(path);
if (ret == 0)
{
    printf("error sending file\n");
}
```

Comment: "And am I guaranteed that the full file will be sent and received?" --> No guarantee.  Good code looks for potential problems in communications.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that using the while loop. If the full buffer doesn't get sent, I sent the rest.

Answer (score 2):

**Various `size_t`**

As the `size_t` is not specified to be the same across *Windows*, nor the compile version of the sender and receiver code the same, nor is the size of file limited to `SIZE_MAX`, I would consider instead a fixed size like `uint64_t` and have the receiver test for fit if needed.

Good that even though OP has "windows", sending/receiving the size is done in  network byte-endian order.

**Lack of error handling**

On error, code should break the loop or `return`.

```
   if (intReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
     printf("error recv buffer size\n");
     // Add return, do not go on.
   }
   intTotalReceived += intReceived;
```

`size = fwrite(buf, 1, res, copyFile);` does not test the return value for being less than expected.

**Minor: Use `const`**

As `int sendFile(char path[100])` does not change `path[]`, consider `const`.

```
// int sendFile(char path[100])
int sendFile(const char path[100])
```

The naked magic number 100 deserves description. As I see it there is no need to limit to 100.

```
int sendFile(const char *path)
```

**Why send 0 bytes?**

If the return value of `fread()` is 0, little reason to send.

```
size = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, originalFile);
// Perhaps add `if (size == 0) break;` or change outer loop stop condition.
int r = send(ClientSocket, buf, size, 0);
```

**Files bigger than `INT_MAX`**

Code will certainly not meet "And am I guaranteed that the full file will be sent and received" in this case.

Lots of `int` variables that mess up send large files like `totalRead < (int)test`.  I recommend `uint64_t`.

`int sizeFile = getSizeFile(originalFile);` is also such a problem.

**Clean-up on errors**

Are all resources clean-up on error?

Example: `printf("3 error %d\n", WSAGetLastError()); return 0;` should also `fclose()` the file.

**Opinion: 0 implies error?**

More C idiomatic to have 0 imply success.  IOWs, return an error code.

```
// if (r == 0) {
if (r) {
  printf("file error %d\n", r);
```

**To the next level**

Communication is wrought with lots of pitfalls.  Consider forming a 64-bit check code on the data sent and append this to the end.  The receiver can use this to verify success.

**Consider *streaming***

Rather than send a file length, simple send a packet of file data with the first bytes indicating packet size.  This helps with files whose length is indeterminate at the beginning like sending `stdin`.

**Errors on `stderr`**

Error message deserve to be sent on `stderr`, not `stdout`.

For wider application, I would forego any message and return error codes and let the caller print anything if desired.